# Using loops to AppendChild nodes in XML with powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have some xml that looks like this...

```
<process>

<stage><stage />
<stage><stage />
<stage><stage />

<process />
```

I am trying to add a  childnode to each of those  nodes and add a new node called   to get something like this....

```
<process>

<stage>
<display><display /> 
<stage />
<stage>
<display><display /> 
<stage />
<stage>
<display><display /> 
<stage />

<process />
```

I wrote this in Powershell

```
[XML]$Document = Get-Content "File Path"

$varChild = $Document.CreateElement("display" , $Document.NamspaceURI)
$counter = 0

do {

$Document.process.stage[$counter].AppendChild($var)
$counter += 1

} while ($counter -lt $Document.process.stage.count)
```

My troubleshooting has revealed that what is happening is that the node gets appended to the First stage node BUT THEN it gets removed and added to the second stage node......I have no idea why or how to add it to all of the stage nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following with your example XML:

```
[XML]$Document = Get-Content "File Path"
$Document.process.SelectNodes("//stage") | ForEach-Object {
    $node = $Document.CreateNode("element","display",$Document.NamspaceURI)
    $_.AppendChild($node)
}
```

**Explanation:**

You convert your XML content into an `XMLDocument`. Use the `SelectNodes()` method with an XPath to select your `stage` nodes. Create a new node for each iteration and append it to the current `stage` node (`$_`).